# Getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception, when using SQLDataAdapter with SQL Functions

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, exception, sqldataadapter

I'm trying to use SQL Functions with SQLDataAdabter, but when i run my application i get this exception :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

in that line :

```
adbtr.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

And when i remove that line, i get the same exception but in the line after:

```
adbtr.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Select_gallery_names_FN()";
```

Here's my code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataSet dst = new DataSet();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adbtr = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adbtr.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        adbtr.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Select_gallery_names_FN()";
        try
        {
            int result = adbtr.Fill(dst);
            if (result == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            cat_repeater.DataSource = dst;
            cat_repeater.DataBind();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your table name is `Select_gallery_names_FN()` ?

Comment: What are you setting the value of your `SelectCommand` twice?

Comment: It's not a table, it's a inline table valued function and it's breaking because you don't have the schema in front of it. If you're using the default schema try "Select * From dbo.Select_gallery_names_FN()"

Comment: I'd be curious to see the contents of the function. You're not passing any variables so is there a particular reason you can't use a view instead?

Comment: @Love2Learn - Yes, I got that.  But, look just above `protect void Page_Load`, he has the 'SelectCommand.CommandText' being assigned there too.  Hence, my question.

Comment: @Love2Learn What do you mean by a `view` ? sorry i'm quite a beginner to this :)

Comment: @Brian Sorry, it's just a bad editing. Fixed now.

Comment: @Brian Ah, I didn't see that, it doesn't really make any sense up there anyways since it hasn't been initialized, but I see what you were saying.

Comment: A view is a SQL object that is kind of like a programmable table. My off the cuff definition would be that a view is a kind of synonym representation of a query.

Comment: I'm guessing that the initialization answer below is correct, but you also need to put the schema in front of the function to avoid a downstream error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize the `SelectCommand`.. it is `null` at the time you're setting properties on it:

```
SqlDataAdapter adbtr = new SqlDataAdapter();
adbtr.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Select_gallery_names_FN()");
adbtr.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```